# Server Side Processing for DataTables in Yii2

Tags: datatable, yii2

I am a little bit new to using dataTable though i have used it on small results but I am stalked on how to implement it on large data. I have over 9000 records and as a result of this, it triggers Unresponsive script anytime i try it on Mozilla Firefox and also it runs slower. I need your expertise on how to implement server side processing dataTable. My Codes can be found below

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        if(Yii::$app->user->can('viewAsset')){
            $model = IgrBusiness::find()->all();
            return $this->render('index',compact('model'));
        }else{
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
```

Javascript that runs the dataTable is found below

```
<?= $this->registerJs('
   $("#gridTable").dataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [ 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120,140 ], 
        "pageLength": 40,

   });
') ;?>
```

Thanks in anticipation for your help.

Comment: Why you don't use gridview ?

Comment: I have done some with the grid view but I am trying out a new stuff with the data table....

Comment: Thanks. I have already figure it out using yii2 gridView. I think it is quite faster than when using dataTable. Thanks for the tip.